# Content Type being overwritten when sending to Azure Blob container

Tags: azure, npm, azure-blob-storage

So within my code I have set for the content type to be replaced by whatever is being uploaded but Azure keeps overwriting it with the default of application/octet-stream. I can see that in the network tab that the content-type is image/png and that in the axios request via http, in the config header it's been set for content type but then when going into the container to view the file, it's application/octet-stream.

As a note, I am using the npm package vue-azure-blob-upload

```
 http.put(uri, requestData,
        {
          headers: {
            'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
            'Content-Type': state.file.type,
            'x-ms-version': '2020-10-02',
            'x-ms-date': new Date(),
          },
          transformRequest: [],
        }).then(function (response) {
        $log(response);
         }
```

Within http.js:

```
init() {
    axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'image/png';
},
```

[image: The console log for after the request has been sent]

Comment: Please try by changing `Content-Type` header in your request to `x-ms-content-type`.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried that it didn't work, but by adding blob in so it became `x-ms-blob-content-type` it worked, so thank you for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Sorry...my bad! Yeah it is `x-ms-blob-content-type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri). Adding your comment section suggestion to answer to help other community members.

> Change the `content-type` header in the request from `state.file.type` to `x-ms-blob-content-type`